# API for fetching movie details from IMDB or similar sites?

Tags: python, django, movie, imdb

I've tried using OMDb, it gives all the things I need and has a very simple working too, but it is very very slow. I looped about 200 queries and it took about 3 minutes to complete.

Is there any faster API out there that can give me similar results on querying an movie. The details i'm looking for in particular are genre, actors and director.

My base code is written in python (for my django server), so an API with a wrapper would just make my day

Answer (score 0):

If you have a server which is frequently used, you could think about caching the information locally. I suppose it's very likely that most queries will be clustered around a reduced set of movies, so that would speed up your search.

Comment: The query to the OMDb API is only going to happen only once when the client logs in the first time and the data I fetch will be stored in the db. It's a sort of initial setup. 
But if the query is taking 1sec per query, it becomes a little slow. Is this a good enough speed, am I expecting too much?

Comment: I am fairly sure services like OMDb have a mechanism in place to 'pace' requests - to avoid people downloading the entire database and reuse it. Who knows - it may well be 1 second per consult.

Comment: Well I spoke to Brian Fritz myself about it. It's just that he's working some caching due to which there are slowdowns right now. But when I tried it again without logging it was happening in somewhat <1s, but not close to 500ms.
Anyway, thanks man.